# Why is hot water coming out of the faucet but the shower is ice cold? (Diverter not on spout)

Tags: shower, faucet, tub

My shower has 3 knobs & the spout. The diverter (that turns from spout to shower) is in center of shower wall between hot & cold knobs. I've checked to ensure the diverter knob is fully turned onto shower. Is it difficult to fix/replace when the diverter isn't on the tub spout?

Comment: Are you saying that you have separate hot/cold knobs, and you can turn on only the hot and get hot water from the spout. But when you turn the diverter to the shower head, the water now comes out the shower but it remains cold?

Answer (score 1):

If you get warm water out of the spout and cold water out of the shower head, then I sounds like you've isolated the potential problem to the diverter (only other thing that comes to mind is some kind of water pressure based issue, but I can't think of where that would happen on the hot water side only since you have separate hot/cold knobs).

Since this is after the hot/cold knobs, you can probably fix this problem without even shutting off the water, just place something over the drain (don't want to lose a screw), disassemble the diverter, see if it's just an o-ring or dirt, and if not, replace the entire part (take the old one to the hardware store to find an exact match).

Comment: Won't water spray everywhere when you remove the diverter?

Comment: @stannius diverter comes after the taps to turn the water on and off.  So as long as you leave the taps off, no water will come out (besides the little bit left in the pipes).